# R: repeat a for loop which uses two variables in a dataset for the rest of the pairs of variables in the dataset

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have a dataset containing pairs of a lot of variables/columns, for example `a1` and `a2`, `b1` and `b2`, `c1` and `c3`, etc.

I've written a for loop in `R` which creates a new variable `a_new` using both the columns `a1` and `a2` (specifically, I am using an `if else` function in between the for loop).

I want to do the same for the rest of variables/columns, creating columns `b_new`, `c_new`, etc. from `b1` and `b2`, `c1` and `c2`, etc. without writing 100 for loops, so I maybe need to use one of the apply functions (or another for loop which loops around the for loop I already have?).

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You should probably provide your `for`-loop.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Exactly what is the rule that creates `a_new`?

Comment: Sure, this is my code:

for (i in seq_along(a1_new[i]))
for (i in seq_along(a1_new)){
  dataa$a1_new[i] <-if(is.na(a1[i])==TRUE & is.na(a1[i])==TRUE){
    a2[i]} else {a1[i]}
}
write.csv(dataa, "a_final.csv")

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As you don't provide any code example I will asume that you're just adding up one column to another.

In this case you can:

```
#Dummy data    
DF=data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))

#For loop
for(i in (which(seq(1:ncol(DF)) %% 2 == 1))){
DF[paste("new_",i,sep="")]=DF[i]+DF[i+1]}
```

This will create a new column within  "DF" with the result of the first column in "DF" + the second column in "DF". The operation can change in any way you want.

As it use `ncol(DF)` into the loop it will adjust to the size of the table you're working on.

Comment: Sure, this is my code:

for (i in seq_along(a1_new[i]))
for (i in seq_along(a1_new)){
  dataa$a1_new[i] <-if(is.na(a1[i])==TRUE & is.na(a1[i])==TRUE){
    a2[i]} else {a1[i]}
}
write.csv(dataa, "a_final.csv")

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user7502433 for a good reproducible example you need to provide the dataframe or part of it and the code; edit your post, and add all the info. As far as I can guess from the info you gave, my solution works but you need to adapt your code. Work on it, and remember people in stackoverflow don't like to write specific codes for specific data you just because you don't know how to.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much for your help! And Sorry!